# include only scoped records in ranscak search instead of all records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ransack

I have Employee applications class with each Employee has to select in the application a Software that he can use, and then I have a search form using ransack, but when I search for the employee applications by software, I want to get only the employees applications that have selected that software, instead it returns all the employees applications, because apparently it is not using that scope or the filter in the ransack query
So how can I use the scope or write the right query to include only the records with selected?

```
class EmployeeSoftware < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :employee_application

  scope :selected, -> { where(selected: true) }

end
```

```
class EmployeeApplicationsController < ApplicationController

    
    def index
      
        @search = EmployeeApplication.ransack(q)

        @employee_applications = @search.result.to_a.uniq

    
    end
end
```

the view

```
= form.select :employee_softwares_id_in, options_from_collection_for_select(employee_software_options_for_select, "id", "name", @search.employee_softwares_id_in)
```

any idea how can I do it?

Update: I managed to add the field through the view and it will be included in the ransack query, don't know if there is a better way but this one worked out

```
= form.select :employee_softwares_id_in, options_from_collection_for_select(employee_software_options_for_select, "id", "name", @search.employee_softwares_id_in)
= form.hidden_field employee_softwares_selected_eq, value: '1'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add scope in your controller action

```
class EmployeeApplicationsController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @search = EmployeeApplication.selected.ransack(q)
        @employee_applications = @search.result.to_a.uniq
    end
end
```

OR

you can use `default_scope` which will be applied every time when you try to search.

```
class EmployeeSoftware < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :employee_application
  default_scope -> { where(selected: true) }
end
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: The first one didn't work as the EmployeeApplication itself doesn't have the `selected` scope,it is in the EmployeeSoftware model
The second one worked but the problem that I will have all the softwares selected when I trying to fill the form at the first time but it returns the query I want to use, how can I use it through ransack?
SELECT "employee_applications".* FROM "employee_applications" LEFT OUTER JOIN "employee_softwares" ON "employee_softwares"."selected" = TRUE AND "employee_softwares"."employee_application_id" = employee_applications"."id" WHERE "employee_softwares"."id" IN 16729

Comment: can you add scope in `employee_application` and check once ?

Comment: I tried but still, is there a way to just add the condition `selected: true` to the ransack query so it returns it as in this part  `SELECT "employee_applications".* FROM "employee_applications" LEFT OUTER JOIN "employee_softwares" ON "employee_softwares"."selected" = TRUE `

Comment: You can also search by any predicate on the associated model https://activerecord-hackery.github.io/ransack/going-further/ransackers/#associations

Comment: Cut me off from edit also see https://activerecord-hackery.github.io/ransack/going-further/associations/ and if you want to use scopes you have to enable it with `def self.ransackable_scopes(_auth_object = nil)`, which should return an array of scopes, in your case might only be `[:selected]` then you use scope name in the query params.